# AJAX call to retrieve text data in text file with a different extension fails (404)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to retrieve the text data in a file by the following simple AJAX call, where the text data is on the server in a file with extension ".URL" (uploaded as a Windows 10 shortcut link).  A .URL file is pure text incidentally, editable with any text editor.

```
$.ajax({        
    url: relativefilepath,      
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);        
    },      
    error: function (error) {   
         alert("error=" + error.status);        
    }   
});
```

For the .URL file, the call returns error code 404.
However, if I rename the file on the server to have a .txt extension, the call succeeds.  Does AJAX require text files to have the .txt extension?  If possible I'd like to be able to retrieve the text data without renaming the file.

Comment: "Does ajax require text files to have the extension ".txt"?" - no.

Comment: Be aware that unix-based filesystems (such as your web server might be) are generally case sensitive. Check the filename carefully. Is it `.URL` or `.url`?

Comment: Make sure to use `dataType: "text"` in your call.

Comment: @cнŝdk a change to the `dataType` won't fix a 404

Comment: _"uploaded as a Windows 10 shortcut link"_  uploaded _how_, exactly?

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ too. Compare the requested URL with what you expect it to be. Can you load the correct URL directly in your browser?

Comment: @Phil, confirmed that the request (url parameter) is specified as ".URL" (upper case)

Comment: Right, I tried adding dataType: "text", and still 404.

Comment: @Phil, I uploaded it through FTP, so it's exactly the file that Windows created.

Comment: @Phil   the URL info (in the text file) is correct (propertly sends a browser to the correct location), but it doesn't matter since I'm not even able to get the text from it.

Comment: A little more info about this: When a Windows desktop shortcut link is created by dragging a url from a browser, it can be opened in Notepad, for example, as simple text, so I assumed it was basically a text file.  When uploading it by FTP, it gets saved on the server with the extension ".URL ".  It is the url itself as plain text that I want to access by the AJAX call.

Comment: @Phil My comment "the URL info (in the text file) is correct (propertly sends a browser to the correct location), but it doesn't matter since I'm not even able to get the text from it." was in response to that comment.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear... at what URL do you expect to find this file? Eg, `http://example.com/my.URL`. Can you open that file directly in your browser? Check your browser's _Network_ console and see if the AJAX request is loading the expected URL

Comment: @Phil   The file is in a directory relative to the javascript file making the AJAX call, so the url: parameter looks like "reldir/subdir/filename.URL".
I should emphasize that if the ".URL" extension is changed to ".txt", the call succeeds and I can access the data received.